# Getting video embed in UIView and stop it

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am using a WebView to show a web page with a video embedded in it, and when the page is loaded the video starts automatically. What I want is to have the video stopped or paused when the web page is loaded. Is there a way I can do this from the app or from the WebView? My current code for loading the web page is below:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webViewRv: WKWebView!        

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL (string: "page url");
        if let unwrappedurl = url {
            let request = URLRequest(url: unwrappedurl)
            let session = URLSession.shared
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request){ (data, response, error) in
                if(error == nil)
                {
                    self.webViewRv.load(request);
                }else{
                    print("ERROR: \(error)")
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post irrelevant code in your questions (e.g. `didReceiveMemoryWarning` has nothing to do with this)

Answer (score 0):

Set the WKWebView's configuration's [`mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration/1851524-mediatypesrequiringuseractionfor) to `.all`.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the response i'm trying to do what you said.

i add this function to the class above:

override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = .all
    }

but im receiving this error when running the app :

Thread 7: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on the "self.webViewRv.load(request);" line.

Thanks